# How can I make a for loop that uses entire string instead of just one element

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have a list from a dataframe

`print(crypto)`

```
              Ticker       Site                             Date
0           Dogezilla-(DOGEZILLA)-    Hotbit   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 11:19:14 +0000
1                    Epanus-(EPS)-    Hotbit   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 10:48:16 +0000
2           Gods-Unchained-(GODS)-      OKEX   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 08:43:12 +0000
3                       LIQ-(LIQ)-      OKEX   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 08:33:13 +0000
4              Samoyedcoin-(SAMO)-      OKEX   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 07:33:11 +0000
5                GameZone-(GZONE)-      OKEX   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 07:23:11 +0000
6                   Aurory-(AURY)-    Kucoin   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 06:53:12 +0000
7             BASIC-Token-(BASIC)-    Kucoin   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 06:43:15 +0000
8                   Exeedme-(XED)-    Kucoin   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 06:38:12 +0000
9                 Metahero-(HERO)-    Kucoin   Fri, 29 Oct 2021 06:23:11 +0000
```

The list is

```
Tick = list(crypto['Ticker'])
Tick = re.sub(r'-\(.*?\)-','', str(Tick))


['Dogezilla', 'Epanus', 'Gods-Unchained', 'LIQ', 'Samoyedcoin', 'GameZone', 'Aurory', 'BASIC-Token', 'Exeedme', 'Metahero', 'Smart-Valley', 'Dollar-Factory-Finance', 'YDragon', 'Sushi', 'YooShi', 'Gogeta-Inu', 'Songbird', 'OmiseGO', 'Synthetix-Network-Token', 'Sushi', 'PancakeSwap', 'SHIBA-INU', 'Axie-Infinity-Shards']
```

If I make a for loop saying something like

`[print(item) for item in Tick]`

It will give an output that's letter by letter

```
[
'
D
o
g
e
z
i
l
l
a
'
,
 
'
E
p
a
n
u
s
'
```

What I want to  do is make a for loop that looks like

`[cg.get_price(ids=item, vs_currencies='usd') for item in Tick]`

However this just goes letter by letter breaking the function. So if I want to have a function that puts each string from the list into the ids input.

Comment: It sounds like `crypto["Ticker"]` is a string to begin with, and you're turning it into a list of characters, and then working on the string representation of that list. Without seeing your original data it's hard to help.

Comment: @AKX here I'll make an edit with the dataframe

Comment: When you say `for item in Ticker` -- what are you wanting to iterate over?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I want to iterate over each string if thats what you mean. For Example, 'Epanus' would be an input for the for loop. Then I want the loop to go into the 'ids = item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: using code from AKX's answer, and building on it:

```py
crypto['Ticker'] = crypto['Ticker'].str.replace(r'-\(.*?\)-', '', regex=True)
crypto['Price'] = crypto['Ticker'].transform(lambda item: cg.get_price(ids=item, vs_currencies='usd'))
```

---

I think your code doesn't do what you want it to because you're converting `Tick` (a `list`) to a `str` when you do `str(Tick)`. Instead of

```py
Tick = list(crypto['Ticker'])
Tick = re.sub(r'-\(.*?\)-','', str(Tick))
```

do

```py
Tick = [i.split('-(')[0] for i in crypto['Ticker']]
```

and iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks it probably would've taken me an hour to get the price back in the dataframe haha

Comment: @Lonesomewhenuraround esp. when working with dataframes, it can be tempting to take your data out (e.g. into a list), iterate over it, and then put it back into the dataframe -- but there's (almost?) *always* a (better!) way to do it in-frame *without using a `for` loop*.

Answer (score 2):

Right – given the information that `crypto` is a Pandas dataframe and `crypto['Ticker']` refers to a series in it, you might want to just

```
crypto['Ticker'] = crypto['Ticker'].replace(r'-\(.*?\)-', '', regex=True)
```

to fix those ticker symbols in-place.

Comment: Might need to do `crypto['Ticker'].str.replace...`

Comment: That worked thanks! I didn't think I could use regex on a dataframe